# Access Update Query Crashes Program

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I've recently moved a db built in *Access 2010* to *Access 2013*. It was working fine for a while then it suddenly started crashing (i.e. not responding) whenever a certain table is updated using VBA. I can run the query on its own without any problem but can't call it in VBA. Below is an example of the code that would cause a crash. Any attempt to update this table causes it to crash:

```
Sub ShipOrder(OrderID As Long)

Dim strSQL As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

strSQL = "UPDATE Orders SET StatusID = 20 WHERE ID = " & OrderID

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

I've already moved all tables, forms, etc. to a new database just in case the old one was corrupted but the problem persisted.

Any suggestions on what is causing this error are greatly welcome!

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to edit the data that way. The table doesn't appear to be locked

Comment: Long shot: have you tried compact and repair? File/Info menu. It sometines solved mysterious errors for me.

Comment: does it always crash on the same query? Is the table linked or local ?

Comment: Yes, always on the same query. Yes the table is linked.

Comment: Are you sure it is not calculatig or running the query for a long time? How many records are we talking about? Hmm, I guess ID is a primary key, so it is indexed, in which case it shouldn't take long even for gazillions of records...

Comment: The table is linked ok.... to what? Is it another ACcess DB or another RDBMS ? if the latter provide the ODBC driver used

Comment: It's seldom more than 5 or 10 records at a time. I have let it run for several minutes but it doesn't come back. It's a pretty straightforward update. It seems like a bug but I can't find any information on it anywhere.

Comment: It's linked to an Access DB. They are running on the same machine while I try to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Try this: Create a new table in a new DB. Let it alone, just the table that crash. And create a new linked table to that one, name it `Orders2` and adapt your UPDATE statement to query `Orders2`

Comment: I tried replacing the sql statement with loop through a recordset updating each record individually. I get the same result- crash.

Comment: I just created the Orders2 table in a separate db and changed the UPDATE statement to query it. I got an error message saying it could find a table or query named "OrderInvoices" which is a table in this db but not referenced at all in the SQL statement. I'm not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: I think there are macros on the back end table that are not running correctly and causing this crash. At least that may explain this new error message.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like your linked DB is the problem..
Did you try-

```
docmd.RunSQL ""
```

may be CurrentDb on CurrentDb.Execute is the problem...

good luck..